# JAX-RS: Resolve URI of Linked Resources on the Server

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs

is there a standard way (JAX-RS) to resolve REST URIs to resources on the server side? As I understand the common practices, it's best to provide a full URI as an identifier for resources. If I want to allow somebody to POST/PUT a document like this to create/change a product:

```
<product>
    [...]
    <categories>
        <category>http://.../rest/categories/12</category>
        <category>http://.../rest/categories/35</category>
    </categories>
</product>
```

As you can see, the references to the categories are their resource URIs. On the server side I now have to resolve these URIs to the corresponding resources. The simplest approach would be to create a client for the service on the server itself and do a standard GET request on these URIs. But I feel like this shouldn't be necessary.

Is there a standard way to do this? Is there a CXF way to do this? Is it better to always provide an additional id as well?

Thanks.

Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for -
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceContext.html

It is not from CXF or JAX-RS but from Jersey. I used it to parse documents just as in your example.

Inject it using @Context into your resource to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I cannot use Jersey. I see there is a method UriInfo.getMatchedResources() in the standard. Would this help? How can I create a new UriInfo instance?

Comment: Sorry did not notice the comment earlier. @Context UriInfo would DI the current instance of UriInfo into a resource and I am not sure about the getMatchedResources() method behavior, haven't used it earlier.